# heroku ignore .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, heroku, yii2

I am deploying a yii2 project to heroku. I need to redirect all requests on https://. I added a .htaccess file to frontend/web folder (in environments heroku/frontend/web). On local its working, but on heroku it's not. What's wrong? When the app is deploying I can see that .htaccess is generating by init.php, but if I access http://www.my-finesse.com redirect is not working :(

```
RewriteEngine On

# If we receive a forwarded http request from a proxy...
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http [OR]

# ...or just a plain old http request directly from the client
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =""
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on

# Redirect to https version
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```